# Memory leaking issues in iOS 5 SDK project with ARC enabled code

Tags: ios5, memory-leaks

I am using XCode 4.2 with iOS SDK 5 and building my project using ARC. On testing the project for Memory Leaking I have found some leaks and when I click on details it takes me to

@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass

below are the screenshots, how can I drilldown more to find the specific code which is causing the issue. I have searched on web and have found that there are some memory leaking issues with iOS SDK 5.0 , is this leaking due to iOS SDK 5.0 issues ?

(I dont want to update my development environment before I get certain that this is due to iOS 5 SDK built-in issues.)

thanks in advance for your help & support.
[image: memory leaking]
[image: code calls]
[image: pointing to @autoreleasepool]